# Put the line at previous position

Tags: java

I am trying to do the following after finding this line `Min:30` or `Min:15` in the text document I want to write it after this line `stop mon-fri` in the new text document or if it possible in the same text document and then delete the empty newline where the `Min:` line was found. With the current state the line are being changed and not located as in the result simple. How can I fix it?

I appreciate any help.

**Simple:**

```
4
stop mon-fri
Chinese 
death Radbruch-Platz 
operator 
Min:30
apologized 
cooperate 
4
stop mon-fri
government computers 
WASHINGTON 
suspected 
Min:15
Chinese 
hackers
```

**Result should looks like this**

```
4
stop mon-fri
Min:30
dominant 2
death Radbruch-Platz 
operator 
apologized 
cooperate 
4
stop mon-fri
Min:15
government computers
WASHINGTON 
suspected 
Chinese 
hackers
```

**Code:**

```
try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(path + File.separator + newName);
     Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)) {

    ArrayList<String> store = new ArrayList<String>();
    int indexA = 0, indexB = 0;

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        store.add(line);
        if (line.startsWith("stop")) {
            indexA = store.size() ;
        } else if (line.startsWith("Min:")) {
            indexB = store.size() - 1;
            Collections.swap(store, indexA, indexB);
        }
    }
    for (String element : store) {
        writer.println(element);
    }
    scanner.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: which semicolon do you mean? this is the new try block I must use semicolon there if I want to use this new try notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're reading the entire file in just to write it back out after you perform your modifications, I would just use `Files.readAllLines()` to get all the information into a `List<String>` rather than a `Scanner`.

Once you have your data in the `List<String>`, just iterate through it an you can apply the same conditional checks you're using to find the indexes of the lines you're interested in.

Once you have your indexes, instead of using `Collections.swap()` I would use `.set()` your `List<String>` provides then just do a remove to remove the line that you do no want to keep in your data.

After your done modifying the `List<String>`, you can do `Files.write()` to write it back to the same file.

Code Sample:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<String> myFileLines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("MyFile.txt"));

    // Printing the file before modifications for test purposes
    System.out.println("Before:");
    myFileLines.stream().forEach(line -> System.out.println(line));

    int stopMonFriIndex = -1;
    int minIndex = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < myFileLines.size(); i++) {
        if (myFileLines.get(i).startsWith("stop")) {
            stopMonFriIndex = i;
        } else if (myFileLines.get(i).startsWith("Min:")) {
            minIndex = i;
        } else if (stopMonFriIndex > -1 && minIndex > -1) {
            // Set the Min: line after the stop line
            myFileLines.set(stopMonFriIndex + 1, myFileLines.get(minIndex));
            // Remove the Min: line
            myFileLines.remove(minIndex);
            // Reset indexes
            stopMonFriIndex = -1;
            minIndex = -1;
        }
    }

    // Print the file after modifications for test purposes
    System.out.println("\r\nAfter:");
    myFileLines.stream().forEach(line -> System.out.println(line));

    // Write the data back to the same file
    Files.write(Paths.get("MyFile.txt"), myFileLines);
}
```

Results (From display):

```
Before:
4
stop mon-fri
Chinese 
death Radbruch-Platz 
operator 
Min:30
apologized 
cooperate 
4
stop mon-fri
government computers 
WASHINGTON 
suspected 
Min:15
Chinese 
hackers 

After:
4
stop mon-fri
Min:30
death Radbruch-Platz 
operator 
apologized 
cooperate 
4
stop mon-fri
Min:15
WASHINGTON 
suspected 
Chinese 
hackers
```